# What should I change if I want unit test a method with expression as a parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, automoq

How can I write a unit test for this method:

```
public void ClassifyComments()
{
   IEnumerable<Comment> hamComments = _commentRepository.FindBy(x => x.IsSpam == false);
   IEnumerable<Comment> spamComments = _commentRepository.FindBy(x => x.IsSpam == true);

   //....
}
```

The `FindBy` method takes an expression as a parameter:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    return dbSet.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

This is my unit test so far:

```
IEnumerable<Comment> spamComments = Builder<Comment>.CreateListOfSize(10).All()
    .With(x => x.Content = "spam spam spam")
    .Build();
IEnumerable<Comment> hamComments = Builder<Comment>.CreateListOfSize(10).All()
    .With(x => x.Content = "ham ham ham")
    .Build();


var mockRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Comment>>();
mockRepository
        .Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.Is<Expression<Func<Comment, bool>>>(y => y.IsSpam == true)))
        .Returns(spamComments);

mockRepository
        .Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.Is<Expression<Func<Comment, bool>>>(y => y.IsSpam == true)))
        .Returns(hamComments);
```

But I can't compile it, how can I change this test so that the mocks generate values for `hamComments` and `spamComments`.

> Error 2   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'IsSpam' and no extension method
>   'IsSpam' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Your unit test doesn't seem to make much sense, if `FindBy` is a method on an `IGenericRepository<T>`, then why would you be creating a mock instance of the system you are trying to test?

Comment: I don't want to test method FindBy from GenericRepository class. I need set return value for one and second FindBy in method ClassifyComments.

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: I use AutoMoq. I could use It.IsAny from AutoMoq if I had only one FindBy in method ClassifyComments. Unfortunatelly I have two FindBy with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to recreate the logic you want to test *in your test* and I think that is your mistake.  Try this code:

```
IEnumerable<Comment> spamComments = Builder<Comment>.CreateListOfSize(10).All()
    .With(x => x.Content = "spam spam spam")
    .Build();
IEnumerable<Comment> hamComments = Builder<Comment>.CreateListOfSize(10).All()
    .With(x => x.Content = "ham ham ham")
    .Build();

// Bring both lists together as one (might be a better way to do this)
IEnumerable<Comment> allComments = spamComments.Union(hamComments);

var mockRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Comment>>();
mockRepository
        .Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.Is<Expression<Func<Comment, bool>>>())
        .Returns(spamComments);
```

*NOTE: I'm not a Moq expert, so that syntax above might not be 100% right*

So the purpose of the code in your `ClassifyComments` method is to take a list of mixed `Comment` instances and split them up into their different classifications (spam and ham), so you just want your `mockRepository` to return a single list of comments.

Then it's up to the rest of your unit test to verify that your `ClassifyComments` did what it was supposed to do with the knowledge that it had 10 "spam" and 10 "ham" `Comment` instances.

So as an example, let's assume that your `ClassifyComments` looked like this:

```
public void ClassifyComments(out IEnumerable<Comment> spam, out IEnumerable<Comment> ham)
{
   IEnumerable<Comment> hamComments = _commentRepository.FindBy(x => x.IsSpam == false);
   IEnumerable<Comment> spamComments = _commentRepository.FindBy(x => x.IsSpam == true);

   //....

   // Set the out params
   spam = spamComments;
   ham = hamComments;
}
```

Your unit test would look like this:

```
public void TestClassifyComments() {
    IEnumerable<Comment> spamComments = Builder<Comment>.CreateListOfSize(10).All()
        .With(x => x.Content = "spam spam spam")
        .Build();
    IEnumerable<Comment> hamComments = Builder<Comment>.CreateListOfSize(10).All()
        .With(x => x.Content = "ham ham ham")
        .Build();

    // Bring both lists together as one (might be a better way to do this)
    IEnumerable<Comment> allComments = spamComments.Union(hamComments);

    var mockRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Comment>>();
    mockRepository
            .Setup(x => x.FindBy(It.Is<Expression<Func<Comment, bool>>>())
            .Returns( (Expression<Func<Comment, bool>> predicate => spamComments.Where(predicate));

    // Construct the class which has the ClassifyComments method
    var sut = ...;

    IEnumerable<Comment> ham;
    IEnumerable<Comment> spam;
    sut.ClassifyComments(out spam, out ham);

    Assert.That(spam.Length, Is.EqualTo(10));
    Assert.That(ham.Length, Is.EqualTo(10));                
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok I did a little research on Moq and I think the above code is how you would do this with Moq.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it isn't so easy because list od hamComments and spamComments in method ClassifyComments must be different and now they both have the same 20 elements. In my implementation of ClassifyComments method which I didn't copy it is very important.

Comment: @michael Ok, see if my edits don't better explain the idea I was tying to convey.